# como gravar os dados de uma api com ruby e sqlite3

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sqlite3

Estou criando uma app apenas em ruby, com sqlite 3,tenho que criar o bd no bin setup para salvar os parametros da api,estou tentando fazer desta foma:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'sqlite3'
require 'faraday'
require 'json'
puts '== Instalando dependências =='
system 'gem install bundler --conservative'
system('bundle check') || system('bundle install')

puts "\n== Preparando banco de dados =="

DB_FILE = 'ibge_nomes.db'
begin
  db = SQLite3::Database.open DB_FILE
  db.execute <<~SQL
    CREATE TABLE Estados(
      id integer PRIMARY KEY ,
      sigla varchar(10) NOT NULL,
      nome varchar(100) NOT NULL
    );
  SQL

  response = Faraday.get('https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados?orderBy=nome')
  json = JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_names: true)
  json.map do |dados|
    seed_data = []
    @id = dados[:id]
    @sigla = dados[:sigla]
    @nome = dados[:nome]
    seed_data = %i[id sigla nome]
    seed_data.each do |data|
    db.execute "INSERT INTO Estados VALUES ( ?, ?, ?)", data

  end
  end
rescue SQLite3::Exception => e
  puts e
ensure
  db.close if db
end
begin
  db = SQLite3::Database.open DB_FILE
  db.execute <<~SQL
    CREATE TABLE Cidades(
    id integer PRIMARY KEY ,
    sigla varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    nome varchar(100) NOT NULL
    );
  SQL

  response = Faraday.get('https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/municipios?orderBy=nome')
  json = JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_names: true)
  json.map do |dados|
    cidades = []
    @id = dados[:id]
    @sigla = dados[:sigla]
    @nome = dados[:nome]
    cidades << %i[id sigla nome]
    cidades.each do |cidade|
      db.execute 'INSERT INTO Cidades VALUES (?,?,?)', cidades
    end
  end
rescue SQLite3::Exception => e
  puts e
ensure
  db.close if db
end
```

e apresenta a seguinte mensagem de erro quando dou o comando binsetup

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    11: from bin/setup:24:in `<main>'
    10: from bin/setup:24:in `map'
     9: from bin/setup:30:in `block in <main>'
     8: from bin/setup:30:in `each'
     7: from bin/setup:31:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
     6: from /home/luciane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:193:in `execute'
     5: from /home/luciane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:151:in `prepare'
     4: from /home/luciane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:194:in `block in execute'
     3: from /home/luciane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:37:in `bind_params'
     2: from /home/luciane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:37:in `each'
     1: from /home/luciane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:41:in `block in bind_params'
/home/luciane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:41:in `bind_param': can't prepare Symbol (RuntimeError)
```

Já pesquisei bastante mas não consegui nenhuma resolução
Alguém tem idéia de como resolver este erro?

Answer (score 0):

estava vendo, aparentemente nesta linha

```rb
db.execute "INSERT INTO Estados VALUES ( ?, ?, ?)", data
```

aqui, creio que você gostaria de inserir o `id`, `sigla` e `nome` mas o valor de `data` tem o symbol `:id`

creio que o que você queria fazer seja

```rb
json.map do |dados|
  seed_data = []
  @id = dados[:id]
  @sigla = dados[:sigla]
  @nome = dados[:nome]
  seed_data = %i[id sigla nome]
  data = seed_data.map { |key| dados[key] }
  db.execute "INSERT INTO Estados VALUES ( ?, ?, ?)", data
end
```

para fazer o debug, eu adcionei a gem `pry-nav` e utilizei `binding.pry`

```rb
json.map do |dados|
  seed_data = []
  @id = dados[:id]
  @sigla = dados[:sigla]
  @nome = dados[:nome]
  seed_data = %i[id sigla nome]
  binding.pry # adcionar um ponto de debug aqui
  seed_data.each do |data|
    binding.pry # adcionar um ponto de debug aqui
    db.execute "INSERT INTO Estados VALUES ( ?, ?, ?)", data
  end
end
```